# php if statement works in the reverse way

Tags: php, if-statement

Sorry for the simple question but I'm looking at this code and could not get to a solution.

I'm getting some data from a mssql db

```
$row = sqlsrv_fetch_array( $rs, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC) ;
```

Then I'm doing a simple switch

```
switch($row['data']){
    case 'AA':
       /* do something */
       break;
    case 'AB':
       /* do something */
       break;
}
```

But it isn't working.
So I just put a simple test to check the content, and this is what I get.

```
echo $row['data'];
echo '<br>';
if($row['data'] == 'AB'){
    echo 'ok';
}
echo '<br>';
echo 'end';
```

And I get

```
AB

end
```

Then I did

```
echo $row['data'];
echo '<br>';
if($row['data'] != 'AB'){
    echo 'ok';
}
echo '<br>';
echo 'end';
```

getting

```
AB
ok
end
```

Obviously I'm missing something really simple, but I'm spending a lot of time looking at this astonished.
Thanks

Comment: instead of using echo $row['data']; use var_dump($row['data']); 
This will print the data type as well so you can compare easily

Comment: there is **no error in your code**

Comment: Run `echo "-" . $row['data'] . "-";` and you can see if the variable contains spaces. Technically your varriable can contain characters that are not vissible while printing, but that would be a longshot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

obvioulsy the data in $row['data'] is not 'AB'. probably ' AB'  or 'AB '

try:

```
if(trim($row['data']) == 'AB'){
    echo 'ok';
}
```

Comment: Thanks to all of you. It was so simple that I was going around it... maybe the long working day...

Answer (score 2):

You might have some extra non-printable characters there.
Use `trim` to strip any leading and trailing white space and change your test like this:

```
if( trim($row['data']) == 'AB'){
    echo 'ok';
}
```

---

Update:

to see exactly what `$row['data']` contains you can debug like this:

```
$ascii = '';
for ($i = 0; $i < strlen($string); $i++) { 
    $ascii .= ord($string[$i]).' '; 
}

print $ascii;
```

This will give you `ascii` codes for each character in `$row['data']`